# Qt application Missing characters when 2D datamatrix barcode is scanned

Tags: qt, qml, barcode-scanner

I am facing an issue with scanned 2D datamatrix barcode where I see different characters missing on scans. This issue is happening only on Linux. GD4500 Datamatrix Scanner works as keyboard wedge here and I use event filter installed on qApp (QGuiApplicaiton) to read the scanned data. I see that data is missing when I put qDebug inside event filter.

```
bool USBPortReader::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(obj);

    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);

        qDebug() << "Received data : " << keyEvent->text();
```

I tested using **evtest** application to see if we receive all data from the driver and it prints all data in barcode everytime I scan.

I tried changed the **USB Keyboard speed** of the barcode scanner from 1 ms to 10 ms and it improves the scans (fewer characters are missing afterwards). Cannot increase more than 10 ms as it is the max supported by scanner. Tried scanning the same 2D datamatrix in a separate qml application with text input (same embedded platforrm), same missing character behaviour was observed.

I wanted to try setting keyboardInputInterval property but it is only available for QApplication and not for QGuiApplication. Can someone help me on how I can adjust the setting on QGuiApplicaiton ? I cannot set this directly on X11 as our embedded applicaiton uses eglfs/framebuffer and don't have X11. I am using Qt 5.6.3.

Any leads or support is highly appreciated.

Comment: Trying QStyleHints now where I can set this property.

Comment: How about changing the communication method to serial port?

Comment: Serial scanners work fine. Only USB scanners had this issue and needed a USB based solution.

Comment: Is the character loss consistent or random?

Comment: Character loss is random.